# Perl - system command printing to terminal?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl script that allows me to change the tile of my terminal tabs, however, everytime I run it, a "-n -e" gets printed to my terminal line.  If I leave those options out, just a blank line gets printed.  Is there any way I can execute the system command inside perl, and not have any code remnants show up on my terminal?

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 #sets the title on terminal tabs (mac OSX)
  3 
  4 #use strict;
  5 use warnings;
  6  
  7 #sets title of term window to input from user.  
  8 my $textline="\'echo -n -e \"\\033]0;";
  9 $textline = $textline . "@ARGV" . '\007"\'';
 10 
 11 system "\'$textline\'"; 
 12
```

Thanks

Comment: `system "echo -n -e ..."` without the extra single quotes. With those escaped quotes, you're just dumping a string onto the shell, not a command.

Comment: @Marc B, No, because `''echo -n -e ...''` is the same `echo -n -e ...` to the shell.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine `-n` and `-e` get echoed because your version of `echo` doesn't recognize those options and treats them as literal text to echo.

But you know what, Perl has its own tool for echoing text: `print`.

```
print("\033]0;$title\007");
```

You might need to flush the buffer afterwards:

```
use IO::Handle qw( );
STDOUT->flush();
```

Or just the following if you don't mind turning off buffering:

```
$| = 1;
```

PS - Your quotes (`''echo ...''`) makes no sense, but they collapse into nothingness, so they don't cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the outputs by '>' and '2>' or you can use qx.
For e.g in qx case you can write

```
my $output = qx( $your_command );
```